# Domain of sum of momentum operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

Given the tensor product of Hilbert spaces $\otimes_{i \in \mathcal{Z}} (\mathcal{H}_i, \psi_i)$ (here $\mathcal{Z}$ is the set of integer numbers, $\mathcal{H}_i = \mathcal{L}^2(\mathcal{R}, dx)$ and $\psi_i \in \mathcal{H}_i$), I would like to understand the following things:

1. What is the domain for the sum of two self-adjoint operators $\hat{p}_1+\hat{p}_2$ acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$, where each $\hat{p} = -i \frac{d}{dx}$ is the momentum operator?
2. I would like also to understand what is the domain of existence for the operator defined as limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i = -n}^{n} \hat{p}_i$, and if it is still self-adjoint with dense domain. Any help is really appreciated.

P.S. Here I assume the Von Neumann definition of infinite tensor products of Hilbert spaces, but I am not sure if there are different definitions not equivalent to this one. If yes, I would be happy to study them, so please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Infinite tensor products of Hilbert spaces are generally speaking delicate to define. You would need to clarify what exactly is the Hilbert space you have in mind.

Comment: What does the $i$ subscript in the operator refer to? As it is written you are just summing the same operator $2n$ times

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you, I added more details, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @whpowell96 The "i" in the definition of the momentum operator is the imaginary unit.

Comment: I understand the definition of $\hat{p}$, but what does the imaginary unit have to do with $\hat{p}_i$ and $\sum_{i=-n}^n$?

Comment: @whpowell96 I believe the OP used $\hat{p}_i$ to mean $\hat{p}$ acting on the $i$-th tensor component.

Comment: I feel this is somewhat hard to describe with arbitrary $\psi_i$. If we assume $\psi_i$ has full support in the momentum space, though, you can perform a Fourier transform to the momentum space, change the measures from the Lebesgue measure to $|\psi_i|^2 d\lambda$ so that we have a probability measure, then the domain of the finite sum can be described as consisting of functions in $\mathbb{Z}$-many variables with appropriate boundedness conditions in the momentum space.

Comment: Presumably if $\psi_i$ has full support in the position space, it might also be possible to say the domain consists of functions in $\mathbb{Z}$-many variables with appropriate differentiability conditions, but I don’t know enough about how weak derivatives work in this scenario to figure out the precise statement.

Comment: @DavidGao Could it be that, in the finite sum case, the domain is the union of the domains for each $\hat{p}_i$ on $\mathcal{H}_i$? Independently from the $\psi_i$. For the infinite case, I am not sure how to find the domain and to see the self-adjointness

Comment: @MBlrd What do you mean by “union”? To make sense of this you need to embed $H_i$ into the infinite tensor product. What is the embedding you have in mind?

Comment: @MBlrd Quite honestly, I’m not even sure how you would even define the infinite sum. Under what topology do you want your infinite sum to converge?

Comment: I simplified question 1 focusing on just two momentum operators

Comment: @DavidGao I would like to know if it can converge at least weakly. It would be interesting to see how (and if) it converges, since it has a clear meaning from physics point of view

Comment: @MBlrd Again, assume $\psi_i$ has full support in the momentum space. After Fourier transforming, I presume you would want your limit to act as multiplication by $\sum_{i = -\infty}^\infty k_i$. For this to make sense, you would want the sequence $(k_i)$ to be in $l^1$ almost surely. That can happen if you choose $\psi_i$ carefully - but it also could fail. By Kolmogorov’s zero-one law, that happens either almost surely or with zero probability. In the first case you do get a densely defined self-adjoint operator, while in the second case the limit simply does not exist in any meaningful way.

Comment: @MBlrd For example, if $\psi_i$ is the square root of the probability density function of a normal distribution with mean zero and fixed variance (that is, the variance is independent of $i$), then almost surely $(k_i)$ is not in $l^1$ (in fact, not even in $l^\infty$), so your infinite sum does not make sense in that case.

Comment: @MBlrd Though if the variances of $|\psi_i|^2$ in the momentum space decrease fast enough (so their variances in the position space increase fast enough) you can get a well-defined infinite sum. For example, if I’m not mistaken, then the variance (in the momentum space) decreasing exponentially is enough, assuming $|\psi_i|^2$ all represent normal distributions with mean 0.

Comment: @MBlrd For question 1, if it’s just the tensor product of two Hilbert spaces, the domain is just going to be $L^2$ functions in two variables that admits $L^2$ weak derivatives in both of those variables, so just the Sobolev space $W^{1, 2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/796718/2451